# Saving and updating API request as Django Model?

Tags: python, django, steam

I am currently messing around with the Steam API to get player details, game inventory etc. I am having a little difficulty trying to come up with a solution as to how to save a very expensive API request.

I am getting the entire item schema for a particular game (DOTA2) using

> http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_570/GetSchema/v0001/

This is a very expensive request and thus I need to store this in a database in order to get the item details relating to a particular users inventory.

I have a number of questions:

1. How do I save all this information within a database? Do i need to
   manually create the model and then filter and save the data? If so how to I actually do this?(I.E would I do this at the model level in models.py or would I do this within a view?)
2. Next how would I update any changes made to the item schema when an update is made?
3. How do I make a script that I can only run when required to update the database in the case of Q2 above. One way I can think of is to set up a URL which when visited initiates the update but im not sure if this is the best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really big.
First, You have to set information of your database in settings.py in order to save all the information to a database. You have to set field in models.py to restore all the values to database. For instance,

```
...
name = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,verbose_name='your name')
...
```

Second, When there is a update, there is a request. As soon as you get this request, you can parse it and then save it to database. This can be done right where you get the update request.
Third, I think there are two ways. One is like you said, using URL. The other is invoking the update function directly. This is Python, right? You can invoke any function as you want.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question depends on how you want to handle historical data. If you don't care about historical values in the API (ie. did an attribute change on a weapon between yesterday and today) and instead only care about the current value (ie. what are the attributes on this weapon right now), then you can simply cache your results.

This caching can be done a number of ways, but the simplest would be to save the entire API result to your local database. This also effectively resolves your second question - how do you update it? You pull the new API schema and save that. You don't have to worry about parsing out all the aspects of the schema and only updated what is appropriate. You are also protected from unanticipated schema changes because you just save the entire thing.

If you need historical data, then parsing the response needs to occur. You'll have to model the entire schema and datestamp the values in your system. Each time you check for an update, you'll have to add a new entry into your system. A vast majority of the schema does not change between updates. You'll find a lot of data is duplicated if you don't handle the unchanged data (ie. qualities, originnames, item_levels, and most of the items themselves won't be affected by any given update).

Your suggestion for option 3 is a valid idea, though it requires a manual visit by someone (presumably you). It is probably the easiest to implement though.